# PowerShell - Number in non-sequential range check failing

Tags: powershell, array, range

I have a list of digits, some sequential, some with breaks. Here is an example.
`(1..10),12,15,(30..45),50,53`

When I try and query whether "my number" is in this list – let's say it's `4` – all checks fail.

```
> 4 -in (1..10),12,15,(30..45),50,53
> False

> (1..10),12,15,(30..45),50,53 -contains 4
> False

> ((1..10),12,15,(30..45),50,53).contains(4)
> False

> (1..10),12,15,(30..45),50,53
> 1
2
3
4
etc...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to ["flatten" the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711991/flatten-array-in-powershell) before searching for your value in it.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell's default behavior with commas is to make arrays of arrays:

```
(1..10),12,15,(30..45),50,53 | Foreach {$_ -join ' '}

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
12
15
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
50
53
```

`4` is not equal to `1 2 3 4...`, so the comparison is false.

---

One simple way to get what you're looking by expressing `$()` the list elements separated by semicolon instead of comma, like:

```
$((1..10);12;15;(30..45);50;53) -contains 4

True
```

Similar keywords are unwrapping or flattening a list/array

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Jeff Zeitlin](https://superuser.com/users/675220/jeff-zeitlin). The solution is to "flatten" the array. In my case, the easiest and most compatible way to do this was to pipe the output to `write-output` and then check that.

```
> ((1..10),12,15,(30..45),50,53 | write-output) -contains 4
> True
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple syntax to flatten a collection of arrays
into one array:

```
4 -in @((1..10),12,15,(30..45),50,53 | ForEach-Object {$_})
```